# Корень слова "показываю"

Tags: состав-слова

Какой корень в слове "показываю"?

Answer (score 5):

Корень -каз-: указываю, приказываю, доказываю.

Comment: А у слова "сказка" тот же корень или выделяют отдельный?

Comment: Нет,не тот: сказк/а, хотя исторически от сказ. сказать.

Answer (score 2):

Мнения учёных расходятся: Потиха, Тихонов,Зализняк считают, что корень ПОКАЗ
http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8CКорень: -показ-; суффикс: -ыва; глагольное окончание: -ть.

Панов, Текучёв в грамматико-орфографич.  словаре показывают корень КАЗ,так что ответ неоднозначен. А в слове сказка однозначно корень сказк во всех словарях, современные значения слов сказка и сказать разные.  сказоч/к/а-чередование К-Ч и беглый О

Comment: По вашей ссылке ничего нет. По моему мнению, наличие разных приставок говорит именно в пользу -каз-. В словари, правда, не смотрела.

Comment: Заглянула в  двухтомник Тихонова. Вот там как раз по-каз-а-ть, но указ-а-ть, доказ-а-ть. Честно говоря, логики не вижу.

Comment: Странно, вчера ссылка работала нормально, сегодня нет. У меня в словаре Потихи-корень ПОКАЗ-,а в Текучёве - -КАЗ-. Я и говорю,что мнения разные. А с Викисловарём у меня уже не первый раз: сегодня одно-завтра другое.То ли статьи меняют, то ли с поисковиком что...